# Using ScrollMagic.js as AMD module

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, scrollmagic

How can one use the excellent [ScrollMagic](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic) JS plugin as an AMD module to use with `requirejs` for example?

I couldn't find any reference to that online and looking at the code of `ScrollMagic` it doesn't seem as if it loads as an AMD module.

It does define 2 variables in the `window` level at the end of the module:

```
window.ScrollScene = ScrollScene;
window.ScrollMagic = ScrollMagic;
```

so it seems that a simple `shim` won't do because I'll need to export two variables. Is there a way to export that?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something that works for me, it's little bit of a work around, but it does the trick.

in the `shim` configuration of `requirejs` I use:

```
shim: {
    'scrollmagic': {
        deps:['jquery', 'TweenMax'], 
        exports: 'ScrollMagic', 
        init: function() {
            return {ScrollMagic: ScrollMagic, 
                    ScrollScene: ScrollScene};
        }
    }
}
```

This is to comply with the fact that `ScrollMagic` requires `jQuery` as well as `GSAP TweenMax` libraries to be loaded.

It turns out that using the `init` function of the `shim` and then returning the two variables, does the trick.

BUT - this means that for using the `ScrollMagic` plugin one should use (example):

```
define(['scrollmagic'], function(scrollmagic) {
    var magic = new scrollmagic.ScrollMagic();
    var scene = new scrollmagic.ScrollScene({duration: 200});
});
```

Hoping that this will help somebody in the future...

== **Edit** ==

ScrollMagic 1.3 now supports the AMD pattern, so all this is unnecessary.